# How to use sync from two array in same table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In view i have a list of checkboxes:

```
 @foreach($features as $key => $feature)
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="featuresCheckbox business">
        <input  v-model="property_credentials.features" type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="{{ $feature->id }}" id="test{{ $key }}", {{in_array($feature->id,$property_features)?"checked":""}} />
          <label for="test{{ $key }}" class="checkboxTitle featuresTitle">{{ $feature->name }}</label>
     </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Also i have input where i add some additional stuff:

```
<div v-for="field in fields" class="additional_fields">
   <label>
     <input name="additional_features[]" type="checkbox" value="@{{ field.value }}" checked>
    @{{ field.value }}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs fa fa-close" @click="deleteCheckbox(field)"></button>
    </label>
</div>
```

Now what i need is to sync this two arrays so that i get in pivot table everything what user choose from checkboxes and what enter in input.

I tried something like this but when i delete its not working:

```
  $all_ids= [];
  $all = [];
  if(!empty($existing_additional_features)){
     $all_ids = array_merge($existing_additional_features,$additional_ids);
  }
  else{
    $all_ids = $additional_ids;
  }
  if(!empty($features)){
    $all = array_merge($features,$all_ids );
  }
  else{
    $all = $all_ids;
  }
  if(!empty($all)){

      $property->features()->sync($all);
  }
  else{
    $property->features()->detach();
  }
```

Comment: Try and add after the `detach()` this: `$property->destroy();`

Comment: u mean $property->features()->destroy() ?